# Error: Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

So I'm trying to setup the local environment for a react-native project. I've tried building this project on my windows device and it worked already. Now, I'm trying to do the same in my apple device but for some reason it cannot build it showed this error:

[here is the detailed error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoS4H.png)

When I create a new project using `npx react-native@latest init` it worked fine so I think the local setup is already right.

Here are more details about the environment:
**Device:** Apple M1

**Java version:**

```
openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.68+17-CA (build 11.0.21+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.68+17-CA (build 11.0.21+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

**Node version:** `v16.20.2`

**SDK:** `Android 13 (Tiramisu)`

I have tried several things but nothing have worked. Here are the things that I tried:

- Clean the project and rebuild
- Delete .gradle, .idea, .build folder and rebuild
- Tried `cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache` and rebuild again
- Tried `cd android && ./gradlew clean` and rebuild again
- Upgrade the gradle from 6.9 to 7

Has anyone experience this error and knows how to solve this?